# How to persist request object in a running Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, scope

I am passing HttpServletRequest object to a Thread and then returning it. The Thread is going to get executed for long duration but before that I return request. Hence I am unable to access the HttpServletRequest object in Thread. So is there any way to persist HttpServletRequest object throughout the Threads execution even after completing its session ?

```
 public String execute(HttpServletRequest request){
       Runnable r = new RunnableImplementation(request);
       Thread t = new Thread(r);
       t.start();
       return "Success";
    }
```

Note : Constructor of RunnableImplementation initialize its local HttpServletRequest object and then it is used in its run() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unlikely to need everything in the request object so write a class that stores just the bits that you need and pass an instance of that to your background task instead. The reason for this is that while the original request object won't magically "disappear" at the end of the request (so long as you're holding a strong reference to it, it can't be garbage collected), but who knows what the application server does to its fields? Probably nothing but maybe it nulls them out, maybe it re-uses the object for another request. All of the above are possible.

The 3.0 Java Servlet Specification covers this subject explicitly in section 3.11:

> Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s
>   service method, or within the scope of a filter’s doFilter method,
>   unless the asynchronous processing is enabled for the component and
>   the `startAsync` method is invoked on the request object. In the case
>   where asynchronous processing occurs, the request object remains valid
>   until `complete` is invoked on the `AsyncContext`. Containers commonly
>   recycle request objects in order to avoid the performance overhead of
>   request object creation. The developer must be aware that maintaining
>   references to request objects for which `startAsync` has not been
>   called outside the scope described above is not recommended as it may
>   have indeterminate results.

And use ExecutorService instead of manually launching threads from servlets, as the latter is a very bad idea for scalability.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the request. You need some informations present in the request.

Simply extract them from the request and construct an object with them and pass it to your runnable object.

Here is a sample code:

```
MyThreadRequest myThreadRequest = new MyThreadRequest();
myThreadRequest.setUser((User) request.getAttribute("user"));
Thread t = new Thread(new RunnableImplementation(myThreadRequest));
```